# Using "a lot" or "very much" to answer "how popular is something?"

Tags: sentence-fragments, conversational-deletion, answers

Can I use "A lot" or "Very much" to answer "How popular is somebody/something?"?

A full answer would be "It is very popular", but can I simply replace the answer with "A lot" or "Very much"?

Comment: You could hardly be more exact, but you could add something like _I think_. Popularity is largely opinion and that varies a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even accounting for ***answer ellipsis*** (see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_ellipsis)) (where you don’t feed back the understood parts of the question), the adjective *popular* would need a suitable adverb.

Q: *How popular is he?*

A: *[He is] very [popular].* = *Very.*

Incorrect A: **[He is] a lot [popular].* = *A lot.*

Incorrect A: **[He is] very much [popular].* = *Very much.*

Comment: I suppose not many would 'understand' "A lot [of people really like her/him/it]" etc. Omissions have to be to non-paraphrased answers.